# Como se hace para relacionar las tablas en la migración al ejecutar php atisan migrate

Tags: laravel, datatables, migration

¡Buenas tardes!; en mi proyecto de laravel que se llama proyectolaravel que es un sistema de compra / venta de productos, estoy en un modulos de productos que para ellos voy a desarrollar la migración de la tabla de productos y la relación con la tabla de categorías, para crear el objeto de la tabla con el comando

php artisan make:migration create_productos_table que al darle enter se creo el objeto con lo que defino los campos de la tabla de productos y defino la relación con la tabla de categorias, que en el siguiente link de la documentación de laravel esta:

[Relación de Tablas en Migración](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)

Mi objeto de tipo tabla productos con los campos y la relación es el siguiente:

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('idcategoria')->unsigned();
            $table->string('codigo',50)->nullable();
            $table->string('nombre',100)->unique();
            $table->decimal('precio_venta',11,2);
            $table->integer('stock');
            $table->string('descripcion',256)->nullable();
            $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('idcategoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');

           
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('productos');
    }
}
```

pero al ejecutar la migración con el comando php artisan migrate da un mensaje de error que la tabla categorias ya existe y no deja crear la tabla productos, que adjunto print de pantalla:

[image: Error en la migración de la tabla productos]

¿Como hago para que se ejecute la migración de la tabla productos pero que se relaciona con la tabla categorias pero sin ningún tipo de problemas?. Se les agradece su ayuda.

Revisando la documentación de Laravel sobre las Migraciones en el siguiente link [Laravel - Database (Migrations)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations)

Hay una parte de la documentación de Laravel en la que se valida que si existe una tabla y columna con hasTable y hasColumn por lo que mi esquema de migración de la tabla productos queda de la siguiente manera de acuerdo al código, y me indican si esta correcto (para cuando se ejecuten la migración con php artisan migrate no de problemas de que ya existe la tabla categoria); así quedarías los esquemas de migración para tabla categorias y productos:

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCategoriasTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if(Schema::hasTable('categorias')){

            exit;
        } else {
            Schema::create('categorias', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('nombre',50)->unique();
                $table->string('descripcion',256)->nullable();
                $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
                $table->timestamps();
            });

        } 
        
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('categorias');
    }
}
```

Esquema de Migración para la Tabla de productos:

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProductosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if(Schema::hasTable('productos')){

            exit;

        } else {

            Schema::create('productos', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('idcategoria')->unsigned();
                $table->string('codigo',50)->nullable();
                $table->string('nombre',100)->unique();
                $table->decimal('precio_venta',11,2);
                $table->integer('stock');
                $table->string('descripcion',256)->nullable();
                $table->boolean('condicion')->default(1);
                $table->timestamps();
    
                $table->foreign('idcategoria')->references('id')->on('categorias');
            });    
  
        }
       
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('productos');
    }
}
```

Sus comentarios, se les agradece:

Comment: prueba con `php artisan migrate:fresh` eso eliminará todas las tablas existentes y las creará de nuevo

Comment: @Aprendiz estimado pero al ejecutar php artisan migrate:fresh no va a eliminar la tabla categoria la idea es que cree la relación en este caso la tabla productos con la tabla categorias

Comment: @JoseFernandoFrugoneJaramill fijate si en tu base de datos tenés creada una tabla que se llama `migrations`. Ahí deberías tener una entrada indicando que ya corriste la migración de la tabla categorías. Si no es así, es porque debes haber cargado dicha tabla sin `php artisan migrate` y por eso ahora te dice que ya existe, porque también está corriendo ese archivo. Si podes perder lo que tenés cargado, hacé como dice @Aprendiz `php artisan migrate:fresh` o probá con `php artisan migrate:refresh`.

Comment: @azeós ¡Listo! probre ejecutando la migración con el comando php artisan migrate:fresh, pero se volvió a crear la tabla categoria que tuvo que agregar datos a la tabla categoría, el siguiente link explica https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations

Comment: Estimado @azeós ¡Buenas noches!; revise la documentación de Laravel que habla sobre las migraciones en el siguiente link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations vi una parte del documento que se puede validar para cuando existe una tabla y columna con las funciones hasTable y hasColumn del esquema de migración que en la parte de arriba esta cambios realizados para esquema de Tabla de Categorías y esquema de Tabla de productos que esta el código en la parte de arriba para que me indiques si también se puede validar de esta manera y esta todo correcto, se te agradece tu ayuda.

Comment: Estimado @Aprendiz ¡Buenas noches! revise la documentación de Laravel que habla sobre las migraciones en el siguiente link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations vi una parte del documento que se puede validar para cuando existe una tabla y columna con las funciones hasTable y hasColumna del esquema de migración que en la parte de arriba esta los cambios realizados para el esquema de Tabla de Categorías y esquema de Tabla de Productos que esta el código en la parte de arriba y me puedas indicar si también se puede validar de esta manera y esta todo correcto, se te agradece tu ayuda.